# SQL Server Merge two tables and calculate the missing value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table T1 containing dates and a table R2 containing dates and values.
I would like to make a query to retrieve the dates and values of R2 and group this with the T1 dates for which I need to find the value from table R2

T1

```
Start Date
-----------------------
2018-08-09 09:42:00.000
2018-08-09 09:46:00.000
2018-08-09 09:48:00.000
```

R2

```
Start Date             | Value
-----------------------|-------
2018-08-09 09:40:00.000|1
2018-08-09 09:43:00.000|2
2018-08-09 09:44:00.000|3
```

And the Result

```
Start Date             | Value|Original|
-----------------------|----------------
2018-08-09 09:40:00.000|1     |yes     |
2018-08-09 09:43:00.000|2     |yes     |
2018-08-09 09:44:00.000|3     |yes     |
2018-08-09 09:42:00.000|1     |no      | --> Value found in R2 table (first value before the date)
2018-08-09 09:46:00.000|3     |no      | --> Value found in R2 table (first value before the date)
2018-08-09 09:48:00.000|3     |no      | --> Value found in R2 table (first value before the date)
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, perhaps the not most performant, but should work on any version of SQL Server, it to use a correlated subquery to find the latest start date in `R2` which is less than the start date in `T1`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t1.StartDate,
        (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Value FROM R2 t2
         WHERE t2.StartDate < t1.StartDate ORDER BY t2.StartDate DESC) Value,
        'No' AS Original
    FROM T1 t1
)

SELECT StartDate, Value, 'Yes' AS Original FROM R2
UNION ALL
SELECT StartDate, Value, Original FROM cte
ORDER BY Original DESC, StartDate;
```

### Demo

Comment: It seems to work. Probably not optimal but it works. Thanks a lot